# How to make a concentric circle effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I try to create a concentric circle with a dot but after the effect is bad.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: you can do this **different size of circles** and **different transparency** . you have to use gradient in stock of the circle.

Comment: What's "bad" about the effect?  What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "a concentric circle with a dot"?

Comment: i think that i use this tutorial https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84740/create-dotted-circles-in-illustrator for realise this effect. when i did it. it was bad

Answer (score 1):

- **BACKGROUND LAYER**: rectangle filled with a dark blue color > Block the layer
- **TOP DISK LAYER**: three circles:

  - Rich black small circle on the back
  - Same size small circle > Fill none > Gradient stroke, 3 px and feather effect
  - Big circle > Fill none > Gradient stroke, 2 px

[image: base circles]

- **FIRST BLEND LAYER**: select the *Big Circle* and the *Small Circle* with gradient from the TOP DISK LAYER and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate, move them to a new layer named **FIRST BLEND LAYER**
- Block the **TOP DISK LAYER**
- Select the *Small Circle* and remove the feather effect
- Select both circles > **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** = 22
- Change the stroke width to 1 px

[image: FIRS BLEND]

- **SECOND BLEND LAYER**: duplicate the FIRST BLEND LAYER
- Block the **FIRST BLEND LAYER**
- Using the Direct Selection Tool > Select the *Big Circle* and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> reduce the size proportionally to the center
- Do the same with the *Small Circle* but increasing the size
- Change the stroke width to 0,5 px and change the blend specified steps

  [image: Second blend]
- Add a Third Blend Layer doing the same as the second one
- Select all the blend layers and change the layer blending mode to **Screen** and reduce the opacity

[image: Third Blend]

[image: FINAL DISK]